# How to update messages from a chat whose sent on date is earlier than the start of the chat?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: 1. chats (containing the start_date of a chat), 2. messages (containing the sent_on date of the chat messages).

chats:

```
id, start_date
1, 2015-06-01
2, 2014-06-01
3, 2013-06-01
```

messages:

```
id, message, sent_on, chat_id
1,  messag1,  2015-05-01, 1
2,  messag2,  2015-04-01, 1
3,  messag3,  2015-03-01, 1
4,  messag4,  2015-02-01, 1

5,  messag5,  2014-06-01, 2
6,  messag6,  2014-06-01, 2
7,  messag7,  2014-06-01, 2
8,  messag8,  2014-06-01, 2

9,  messag9,  2013-04-01, 3
10, messag10, 2013-03-01, 3
11, messag11, 2013-02-01, 3
12, messag12, 2013-01-01, 3
```

The problem is that the records from messages with chat_id = 1 and 3 are with earlier `sent_on` dates than chats.id equaling 1 and chats.id equaling 3.

How can we update the `chats` table setting start_date of chats.id 1 equaling the earliest date from messages with chat_id 1 (in this case 2015-02-01 ) and chats.id 3 with the the earliest date from messages with chat_id 3 ( equaling in this case 2013-01-01)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try doing an update join to a subquery which finds the earliest date for each chat in the `messages` table:

```
UPDATE chats c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT chat_id, MIN(sent_on) AS min_sent_on
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY chat_id
) m
    ON c.id = m.chat_id
SET
    c.start_date = m.min_sent_on;
```